400 error code on calling a Google Apps Script Web App
I created and exposed this very simple Google Apps Script:
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log('Data received : ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({status: 'error', message: error.message})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Only POST request accepted.");

With these settings: Execute as me and everyone can access.
But when I try to call it from wordpress with Thrive Automator it fails with 400 error with only this explanation:
"400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  That’s all we know."
I don't find any documentation describing format expected for data sent to a GAS Web App to avoid 400 error.
Regards,
Florent
Here is the data sent by postman with success:
{
    "contentLength": 0,
    "parameters":
    {
        "email":
        [
            "john_doe@fakemail.com"
        ],
        "progression":
        [
            "50"
        ],
        "id_formation":
        [
            "5"
        ]
    },
    "contextPath": "",
    "parameter":
    {
        "email": "john_doe@fakemail.com",
        "progression": "50",
        "id_formation": "5"
    },
    "queryString": "email=john_doe@fakemail.com&progression=50&id_formation=5"
}

And here is the data sent by Thrive Automator with 400 error and something that looks odd to me but I'm not an expert (see this part : {"postData":{"contents":"{"":""}","length":7,"name":"postData","type":"application/json"}):
{
    "postData":
    {
        "contents": "{\"\":\"\"}",
        "length": 7,
        "name": "postData",
        "type": "application/json"
    },
    "contextPath": "",
    "parameters":
    {
        "progression":
        [
            "50"
        ],
        "email":
        [
            "john_doe@fakemail.com"
        ],
        "id_formation":
        [
            "5"
        ]
    },
    "parameter":
    {
        "email": "john_doe@fakemail.com",
        "id_formation": "5",
        "progression": "50"
    },
    "contentLength": 7,
    "queryString": "email=john_doe@fakemail.com&progression=50&id_formation=5"
}

And here is the answer from Thrive Automator team:
Kenneth replied
Nov 6, 5:24am
Hi Florent,
I’m taking over for Kurt. He’s not available at the moment.
I tested the Web App URL you sent us in Thrive Automator. It’s still throwing a 400 error - https://a.supportally.com/i/XL9DNq.
Thrive Automator can send webhook to other platforms like webhook.site or Email Marketing Platforms just to name a few.
When I tested our webhook in webhook.site, this is the JSON data that we get - https://a.supportally.com/i/wE75OP.
It looks like the incorrectly formatted field: "contents":"{"":""}" is due to your Google App Script handing the incoming request in a way that the “contents” field becomes incorrectly formatted.
We can’t provide support for the Google App Script you created. This already falls under extreme customizations. It’s already out of our support scope.
Could you tell us what you’re planning to do with the Google App Script so we can suggest a workaround?
We might be able to help you come up with another solution. We just won’t be able to help you fix the Google App Script you created.
Looking forward to your reply.
Regards

Please provide more specific details or clarify your problem. In particular, please specify what you are using in Apps Script and which API you are calling, as this information is not included in your current script.

Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating "400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know."?

Hi @leylou, for now, as you can see my doPost() method do nothing else than return success or error.

Hi @Tanaike, here is the flow:
1 - Thrive Automator (from my Wordpress site) call my GAS Web App with POST method sending data you can find at the end of my question.
2 - The GAS Web App return 400 error.
So I contacted Thrive Automator team to know if there is a way to format data as postman do or compliant with Google and I'm waiting for an answer. But I'm still looking for any Google documentation describing format conditions expected to understand this 400 error.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand your detialed request to Web Apps. By this, I cannot replicate correctly your situation. So, can you provide the details of Thrive Automator (from my Wordpress site) call my GAS Web App with POST method sending data you can find at the end of my question?

Hi @Tanaike, frankly I don't know what you need more. I even shared data sent in the webhook call. And Thrive Automator is a blackbox so I can only share with you a screenshot of the IHM. Nobody here know what a GAS Web App expect as json format to avoid 400 error? Is it considered as a blackbox too with poor documentation?

Thank you for replying. About frankly I don't know what you need more., I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I thought that in your situation, it is required to correctly replicate your situation "400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.". So, I asked about the details of your request. But, from your reply, I would like to try to correctly replicate your situation using your provided information.

But when I try to call it from wordpress with Thrive Automator This sounds like the problem is a WordPress/Thrive Automator issue, not a Google apps script issue. I wonder whether this would be better off in the WordPress forum?

I’m voting to close this question because belongs in wordpress.stackexchange

Hi @Tedinoz I'm not an expert so perhaps my question is incorrect but: why no one can tell what a Google Apps Webapp expect as an external call. For example: what json format use or not use to avoid 400 error.

why no one can tell what a Google Apps Webapp expect as an external call. But this works OK when you run it manually - so there is no problem with this code? The problem appears ONLY when you run it from Thrive Automator, and perhaps you are assuming that the exact same code is appropriate to use in Thrive Automator. OTOH, I'm suggesting that this may be a false assumption and that the issue is what is the equivalent Javascript code to run from Thrive Automator - and that is, in my view, a question best answered in the WordPress forum.

Hi @Tedinoz I added to my question the answer from Thrive Automator team.


"400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request."

The error message makes it clear that the code you quote is never even executed, and there is thus nothing to improve in the code. Debug the issue at the client, i.e., Thrive Automator or WordPress.
